# What is the etymology of Spock's name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, names, spock, etymology

The title says it all really: **What was the inspiration and/or origin for Spock's name?**  The only other Spock I know of is, of course, Dr Spock who wrote about children - was this at all an influence?

Comment: Per [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock) "*Roddenberry sought an alien-sounding name when he created "Spock", and did not know until later of Dr. Benjamin Spock, the pediatrician and author*"

Comment: @Richard Nice find!

Comment: In-extended-universe there was an inference that Dr. Spock was a human ancestor... it was one novel, one time and I wouldn't know the title if it were right in front of me...

Comment: @Richard Er, oops. Just realised I've stolen your quote. I did find it independently - hope you won't assassinate me for gaining rep out of it! :-o

Comment: @randal'thor whoops!  It's a good answer anyway ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same quote I used in [my other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102066/31394), from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock) but sourced from the book *The Making of Star Trek*, is relevant here too (emphasis mine):

> Roddenberry **sought an alien-sounding name when he created "Spock"**, and did not know until later of Dr. Benjamin Spock, the pediatrician and author.

**However...**

Dr. Spock's book *Baby and Child Care* was published in 1946 and quickly became a huge bestseller, making him a household name in the US and beyond. Roddenberry's two daughters were born in 1948 and 1953, so it seems likely that he would have heard of the real Spock. It's not a very common name, so surely not coincidence. With this in mind, my conclusion is:

### Spock was created to sound alien, but *subconsciously* based on Dr Spock.

Comment: No worries; a very sound answer, especially from one unfamiliar with ST!